# mySQL select based on sum of rows compared to another field value

Tags: mysql

I have a table of invoice items. A single transaction may result in multiple debit items and multiple credit items sharing the same invoice_set_id, I need to compare the sum of the debit items against the sum of the credit items and add the invoice_set_id to the result set if sum(debits) > sum(credits). It should also add to the result if there is no row with a credit amount. Using mySQL. Thanks for any help. Example table and result follows:

```
invoice_item_id  invoice_set_id  credit_debit  amount
62                a22             debit         15.00
63                a22             debit          8.00
64                a22             credit        23.00
65                b23             debit         44.00
66                c55             debit         15.00
67                c55             debit          2.00
67                c55             credit         8.00
```

Given the above, the result set should be:

```
invoice_set_id
b23
c55
```

Explanation: a22 is not returned because the debits and credits are equal, b23 is returned because it has a debit but no credit, and c55 is returned because the sum of the debits is greater than the single credit.

I appreciate any help with this. The actual query is more involved, but I think this particular problem is all I need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this simply using `group by` and `having`:

```
select invoice_set_id
from t
group by invoice_set_id
having sum(case when credit_debit = 'debit' then amount else 0 end) > sum(case when credit_debit = 'credit' then amount else 0 end) ;
```

Another way of expressing the `having` clause is:

```
having sum(case when credit_debit = 'debit' then amount
                when credit_debit = 'credit' then - amount
                else 0
           end) > 0;
```

Comment: Beautiful. Short and sweet. I tested example 1 and the results are just what I was after. Thanks.